# Can you suggest any extended examples on object-oriented software design?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, oop

I am looking for instructional materials on object-oriented software design that are **framed as extended examples**. In other words, over the course of several lessons or chapters, the author would develop a moderately large piece of software and explain the design approach step by step. Ideally, the material would address not only the design of the primary software being built but also offer useful advice on the rest of the development process -- testing, deployment, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[*Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008673/)

Comment: I believe Head First has even started distributing slides and such for academice use.

Answer (score 2):

This is indispensable for understanding large scale oo design.  In though its implemented in c++ the concepts are completely general and can be used effectively on any platform:
[Large Scale OO Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620)

Truly a classic!!